# Unknown object in Visual Stduio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm reviewing a Visual Studio Project.  I've noticed some objects in the solution explorer which I don't recongise.

Based on this icon what are these objects please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it, its a Web Reference, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx